# Capybara-Webkit close webkit_server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, resque, capybara-webkit

I am using Capybara-Webkit to automate some work on a website.
This is done in the background in a Resque task. After some executions there are quiet a lot webkit_server processes, that weren't closed by Capybara. 
So how can I force Capybara to close it at the end?

```
session = Capybara::Session.new(:webkit)
session.visit URL
session.click_button(BUTTON)
....
```

Comment: +1 I've had this problem as well.

Comment: could you post some more code? How do you call your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `page.quit` at end of the each test case to close all the browser instance.